# How to register a collection property to a custom property group

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I would like to register a collection property for a list to a property group that I have already created.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_group = PointerProperty(type=MyGroupClass)
bpy.types.Scene.my_group.my_list = CollectionProperty(type=MyListClass)
```

This could help tidy up my code by simply accessing the list through the property group, rather than just from the scene like normal. Is this possible?

Comment: define  the collection `my_list` as a member  of  the propertygroup. `MyGroupClass`

Comment: Yep, that's it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @batFINGER for the answer.

I just had to use this code instead, using the actual class name instead:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_group = PointerProperty(type=MyGroupClass)
MyGroupClass.my_list = CollectionProperty(type=MyListClass)
```

Comment: well kinda, this is monkey patching but it works Ok. Would rather see `class Foo(PropertyGroup): my_list : bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=Bar)`  and then `Scene.foo = PointerProperty(type=Foo)`.  But would need to monkey patch to have a collection that is also type `Foo`.